# lightning:quickActionAPI alternative to call from a custom lightning app

Tags: lightning, object, quickaction

What is `lightning:quickActionAPI` alternative to call from a custom lightning app?

When I try to call any method from [the spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:quickActionAPI) I am getting the following error: `The API you used isn’t supported on this page. You can only execute this API on record pages.`. After checking [the spec](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:quickActionAPI) we can see that the type of actions with which the `lightning:quickActionAPI` can work is `object`, so it won`t work with custom lightning app.

That is why I am asking what else can I use to perform quick actions in lightning app.

There is not `x-y problem` due to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228959/preset-a-few-fields-in-lightningrecordform-component) question being asked previously. So, please, do not suggest a completely different approach like using `force:recordCreate`, `force:recordData` or `lightning:recordEditForm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [QuickAction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_quickaction.htm?search_text=Quick) class to activate quick actions in the server-side controller. There is *no UI* for quick actions that work outside of Lightning Experience, so it will be up to you to provide the necessary components to render the quick action to begin with. You can start by describing the quick action, rendering a UI using the describe results (e.g. which fields are required), and then use the appropriate call in Apex to execute the Quick Action using the collected parameters. Due to the complexity of the code, I don't have an example for you, but I think this should be enough to get you started.